# Adding shadow to floating UICollectionView headers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` with 2 sections, each one has its own floating header.

My question is if is there any way to add shadow below the header that will be displayed on the collection's cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a pointer to your collection view's header. [(Info)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22835139/2057171)

Then apply following *CALayer?* effect:

## Objective-c

```
    yourObject.clipsToBounds = NO;//necessary, dont change
    yourObject.layer.masksToBounds = NO;//necessary, dont change
    yourObject.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];//color
    yourObject.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;//translucency (alpha)
    yourObject.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5f;//size | spread
    yourObject.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.5f);//direction (x,y)
```

[Convert to Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-shadow-to-a-uiview) as needed.